# How to pass more information through GMSmarker

Tags: swift, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

How can I pass more data with GMSmarker? For example how can I pass the place_ID? there is only one option for marker1.title. I tried marker2.title but it says marker2 could not be found in GMSmarker().

```
            POIManager.testVariable.forEach {
            let marker1 = GMSMarker()
            marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.geometry.location.lat, longitude: $0.geometry.location.lng)
            
            marker1.title = $0.name
            marker2.title = $0.place_id
            marker1.map = mapView

            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
```

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        print(marker1.title!)
        print(marker2.title!)

        return true
    }
```

Comment: In `userData` maybe?

Comment: Thank you that was a good idea it works. But now I only have 2 string values which I can pass instead of 1. What if I want to pass more data? For example 3 or 4?

Comment: Pass a collection of data perhaps, like an array or a dictionary.